# Has anyone gotten "I see your point"?

Tags: discussion

Everyone loves pointy unicorns, but I don't think I've seen anyone earn one yet here. So, in the spirit of the Winterbash, let's take a show of hands for pointy hats. This should work...

*P.s. If you hate hats, ignore this post.*

Comment: Do you see my point?

Comment: Sorta like the pointed conversation [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4338/24168)

Comment: My point is that to get the unicorn hat, pointy meta comments are necessary.

Comment: I infer that there is a unicorn hat that we can get by commenting extensively.

Comment: [Seems][1] like H:SE should be a trivial place to earn the hat.


  [1]: http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/813/1401

Comment: Unicorns and pointy corns never go amiss :P

Comment: Corny points however are jejune.

Comment: Apparently I have not yet seen the point; I'll have to keep trying.

Comment: Well, maybe there is no point in making corny unicorn puns http://instantrimshot.com/ :P

Comment: I suppose only a truly evil moderator would come through here deleting comments...

Comment: That would destroy the whole point of this post :P

Comment: Well I guess I will help everyone achieve a point, with a few up-votes.

Comment: How many points does one need I wonder?

Comment: Would three or for points be enough?

Comment: Or would the number of points perhaps have to equal the bands on the unic'orn?

Comment: I love pointy hats best of all.

Comment: I believe you need five or more points. They might need two points each to count (I'm not quite sure about that, though).

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: I believe we can help each other with points.

Comment: Who voted to close this question? Don't you see the whole point of it?

Comment: I'm not sure if all this point stuff is still active or not.

Comment: It is. Just not on meta

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a past Christmas Bash, and all the hats are back in their boxes.